# What is the tense in "A-t-elle été causée par le mouvement trop rapide de son propre cœur?"

Tags: grammaire, verbes, temps-grammatical

> Eh bien, cette vibration dans sa tête? L'a-t-il imaginée, aussi? **A-t-elle
>   été causée** par le mouvement trop rapide de son propre cœur? Ou le travail
>   d'un homme dans le cachot voisin?

In this excerpt, how shall I understand the sentence "**A-t-elle
été causée** par le mouvement trop rapide de son propre cœur?" I'm especially confused by the words in bold: what is the tense there? When I check my dictionary for the verb "causer", I can only find "causé".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Causer* is here used at the passive voice, in *passé composé* tense and with an interrogative form. With the passive voice, the past participle need to agree in gender and number, just like an adjective. *Vibration* is feminine thus *causée*.

Active voice:

> Le mouvement trop rapide a causé cette vibration.

Passive voice:

> Cette vibration a été causée par le mouvement trop rapide.

Separated subject.

> Elle a été causée par le mouvement trop rapide.

Interrogative:

> A-t-elle été causée par le mouvement trop rapide ?